# TFS2013, Copy project from an old attached collection to a new one

Tags: tfs, copy, project

We have recently installed **TFS2013_Update3**.
We had TFS2010 prior to that with its own Collection.

that collection is now controlled by the TFS2013 machine.

My question/s as follows:

1. How can i copy a specific Project from the old collection to the new one?
2. Should i ask the whole team to check in before that ? and what is the most efficient way of doing that?

Many thanks!

Comment: So your original collection and projects are now available through your new 2013.3 TFS. you have upgraded the 2010 collection and can see the projects? You want to now move one of the projects from the collection on 2013 to a new collection?

Comment: Yes indeed., while keeping history etc..  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you have:

```
NewProject Collection (2013)
+ Some Project
+ Some Other project

OldProject Collection (migrated from 2010)
+ Old Project
```

And what you want to end up with is:

```
NewProject Collection (2013)
+ Some Project
+ Some Other project
+ Old Project
```

If that's the case, then that's not a supported scenario in the product. There are migration tools that can help you do the migration though, but that's not the same thing as an actual merge. You'll lose some data (timestamps of checkins, users that no longer exist in Active Directory).

The tools that can help you are:

- [TFS Integration Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eb77e739-c98c-4e36-9ead-fa115b27fefe)
- [OpsHub Integration Manager](http://www.opshub.com/main/index.php/products/oim)
- [TaskTop Sync](https://www.tasktop.com/sync)
- [Timely Migration](http://www.timelymigration.com/)

Many teams I work with decide that it's far too much work to do a migration including history and simply make the old project read-only, check in the latest version of the code into a new Team Project created in the target collection and continue to build on top of that.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the extended  explanation.  I was thinking of the next scenario:  1. Ask from all the Dev guys to Check in, verify that with TFS sidekicks.  2. Open a new Proj on the 2013 Collection.  3. Map new workspace on my PC and "Get" the current updated project from the old Collection.  4. Add old proj to a new one on the 2013 collection, and checkin changes. Will that do ?

Comment: Yeah that's basically a tip migration that just takes latest. You may need to migrate work items or build results and test results, if you're using these features of TFS as well.

Comment: since its an old collection (2010), i just need the history to be there, all the rest is less sufficient.   Any assistance on that matter would be great.

Comment: I want to move the Project from Old Collection to the New one, while keeping all history.

Comment: In that case you will need to use one of the mentioned solutions, Only the TFS Integration Tools are free. Here is a tutorial. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2011/05/13/tfs-integration-tools-where-does-one-start-part-2-try-a-simple-migration.aspx